# Working around unsupported Correlated Where Subqueries in Hive

Tags: hive, correlated-subquery

I'm trying to figure out a work around for the fact HIVE doesn't support correlated subqueries. Ultimately, I've been counting how many items exist in the data each week over the last month, and now I want to know how many items dropped out this week, came back, or are totally new. Wouldn't be too hard if I could use a where subquery but I'm having a tough time thinking of a work around without it.

```
Select
count(distinct item)
From data
where item in (Select item from data where date <= ("2016-05-10"))
And date between "2016-05-01" and getdate()
```

Any help would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work around is left join with two result set and where second result set column is null.

ie

```
      Select count (a.item) 
            from 
                (select distinct  item from data where date between "2016-05-01" and getdate()) a
            left join (Select distinct  item from data where date <=  ("2016-05-10")) b
            on a.item =b.item
            and b.item is null
```

Comment: This helped out a ton, Thank you!